# Is it possible to get a delphi project to create a lib file as the output of the project?

Tags: delphi, static-linking

I want it to create dll and LIB. because this dll is statically linked to another CPP dll.
so I must have the lib file.

i'm using the IDE of delphi 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Delphi does not generate lib files. It has no use for them.

There are ways to [create a lib file from a DLL](http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/create-lib-file-from-dll/). For example, you can use [*implib*](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/implib_xml.html), if it came with your version of Delphi.

Comment: thanks, i also had someone talled me that i can use Lib.exe to create the lib file.

Answer (score 3):

Using in C++ DLLs created in Delphi (as vice-versa) is pretty easy, but you need to follow simple
rules. I assume you are trying to use Delphi DLL in C++ project:

1. You must use the same calling convention. By default, Delphi uses register convention (__fastcall in
   C++ terminology). Default calling convention for all Windows DLLs is __stdcall, so first modify the
   function declaration in your Delphi source file as follows:

   **function** DoSomething(x, y: Integer): Integer; **stdcall**;
2. When you use __stdcall, C++ expects exported functions in the DLL to have the names followed by the postfix designating the overall size of the params passed to it. Thus, your DoSomething routine should
   become DoSomething@8, taking into account that the size of Integer is 4 bytes and your exports section
   in the .dpr file should look like:

   **exports**
     DoSomething **name** 'DoSomething@8'
3. Create C++ header with function declaration and include it to your C++ project:

   **int** __**declspec**(dllimport) __**stdcall** DoSomething(**int** x, **int** y);
4. If you use C++ Builder or Visual C++, utilize implib utility which creates import library (.lib). There is also a lib tool coming with VC++ which can do the same. Then link with that .lib file instead of .dll.

Comment: 10x for the full explanation!